# Chinese characters showing as question marks

Tags: windows, fonts, phantomjs, wkhtmltopdf

This has been asked before, but I can't figure out what's wrong. I'm printing pdfs using phantomjs `.render()`.

The rendered page is basically a local static site with these properties:

- `<meta charset="UTF-8">`
- `font: normal 17px helvetica,arial,verdana,sans-serif`
- running and tested on Windows locally and Azure Worker Roles
- Chinese language pack installed and working when printing the same page from Chrome (Installed fonts e.g. Arial Unicode MS, SimSun ...)

Latin characters are all fine, just Chinese ones are displayed as "?"

For example [image]

I also tried the entire page in Arial or SimSun only, but no difference.

Any idea how to get this working on Windows?

Thanks!

Comment: <meta charset /> is new for HTML5, is it supported by your phantomjs too? Cause of showing Chinese characters as question mark is Wrong Charset, not Font. if we use a wrong font which does not support the character, Windows will show the character as a blank box.

Comment: You put me on the right track. When everything is UTF-8, Chinese characters display fine, also with standard fonts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a chinese font. None of them is in a chinese font family.

> font: normal 17px helvetica,arial,verdana,sans-serif

Here are some font has chinese char.

> 宋体：SimSun; 黑体：SimHei; 新宋体：NSimSun; 微软雅黑：Microsoft YaHei; 新細明體：PMingLiU

This is much more than a guide.[Chinese Standard Web Fonts: A Guide to CSS Font Family Declarations for Web Design in Simplified Chinese](http://www.kendraschaefer.com/2012/06/chinese-standard-web-fonts-the-ultimate-guide-to-css-font-family-declarations-for-web-design-in-simplified-chinese/)

This has Traditional Chinese fonts.[Chinese web fonts](http://www.wiliam.com.au/wiliam-blog/web-design-sydney-chinese-web-fonts)

Google's font. Sorry for not being a link, there is a limit for me.

> noto-sans-hans

Adobe's typekit

> source-han-sans

Test Html file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>你好中文！</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        p.serif{font-family:"Times New Roman",Georgia,Serif}
        p.sansserif{font-family:SimSun}
        p.s1{font-family: 黑体}
        p.s2{font-family: KaiTi}
        p.s3{font-family: Microsoft YaHei}
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
    <p class="serif">你好中文！111</p>
    <p class="sansserif">宋体</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p class="s1">黑体</p>
        <p class="s2">楷体</p>
        <p class="s3">微软雅黑</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Result

[image]

Lastest to do, try to change your location to china. I don't expect this working, as I tried the phantomjs in win10 ENG preview, working very well. Control Panel > Region > Administrative > Language for non-Unicode programs

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I tried to use SimSun only, gb2312, and still the Chinese characters are "?". Even Arial or Arial Unicode MS should display some Chinese without any changes. I suppose there's a lot of posts in Chinese only about the same problem. Do you have this working?

Comment: @BenjaminE. There is nothing wrong in my chinese environment. I test the sample "rasterize.js". Nothing wrong. But the PDF file is not recognize by the Reader (windows morden app, the default PDF reader in WIn8.1), MS Word, Photoshop, Foxit Reader works fine.

Comment: You are right. It does work. The reason it didn't work had to do with Azure and the language pack on the VM.