# Outputting dates in non-ASCII characters with PHP

Tags: php, utf-8, non-ascii-characters, strftime, chinese-locale

I'm trying to output the date in Traditional Chinese.

I have the date as a Unix timestamp, ( example: "1467244800" ).

I am doing the following:

```
<?php
setlocale (LC_TIME, "zh_TW");
echo strftime("%e %B %Y", $timestamp );
?>
```

What I'm getting output is the Unicode "Undefined" characters:

```
30 ���� 2016
17 �T�� 2016
18 �Q�G�� 2015
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

My HTML headers contain:

```
<html lang="zh-TW">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

And the rest of my Chinese content on the page is outputting fine. If you view the page source you see:

```
<span>最新消息</span>
<span class="pipe">18 �Q�G�� 2015</span>
```

It's only the strftime() dates that appear as "Undefined" characters: ����...

Thanks for looking...

Comment: Do you have the right fonts? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29458106/chinese-characters-showing-as-question-marks.

Comment: Yes @dr0i, this is not a font issue, as you'll see in my question, the rest of the Chinese content on my page is outputting fine, and if you view the page source, you will see the "undefined" characters in the source code:

`<span>最新消息</span><span class="pipe">18 �Q�G�� 2015</span>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Locales not only come in different languages, but also different encodings. The default `zh_TW` locale will probably use some Chinese encoding, while what you want is UTF-8. Hence, use the UTF-8 version of the locale:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'zh_TW.UTF-8');
```

This depends on your specific system and what locales are installed on it. Check that on the command line:

```
$ locale -a
...
zh_TW
zh_TW.Big5
zh_TW.UTF-8
```

To be more cross-platform compatible, you can try several locales:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'zh_TW.UTF-8', 'zh_TW.utf8', 'zh_TW');
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks! This is exactly what I needed. You have made my day!

Answer (score 0):

You must probably tell PHP that all strings are UTF-8. E.g.:

```
    mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
```

Or if the problem is just with this string:

```
    $out = strftime("%e %B %Y", $timestamp);
    echo mb_convert_encoding($out, 'UTF-8', mb_detect_encoding($out));
```

Or if `mb_detect_encoding()`  does not work correctly:

```
    $out = strftime("%e %B %Y", $timestamp);
    echo mb_convert_encoding($out, 'UTF-8', 'CNS-11643');
```

Before version 7 PHP basically does not know the encoding of the strings. Everything is just an array of 8 bit bytes. Getting the right output encoding sometimes works OK at once, but at other times you have to set everything up by hand.

Comment: Thanks for trying, @Matijs, but this doesn't seem to work. Putting the mb_convert_encoding() on my output just converts �Q�� to
 ¤Q¤ë (which is also wrong)!

Comment: While deceze's answer is better (and interesting as it is not mentioned anywhere in the PHP documentation) I am a bit miffed that someone flagged my answer as being wrong. I clearly identified the problem, only mb_detect_encoding() apparently detects the wrong encoding. A fix for which I just added.

Comment: I'm sorry you are miffed Matijs, I really appreciate your contribution, but even with this additional "fix" I can't get your answer to work, (still outputs "¤Q¤ë"). @deceze's answer gives me "十月", which was what I was hoping for...

Comment: *"Before version 7 PHP basically does not know the encoding of the strings"* – this is still the same situation in PHP 7. And you should never use `_detect_encoding`, it is pretty worthless for the most part. Either you *know* the encoding of your strings or you don't, *guessing* it is rarely successful (as you demonstrate).