# I18n to store the translated text into JSON in AEM 6.3

Tags: aem

Currently I am facing one issue in i18n.

I have a service which will read a JSON file and update few properties in the file and store the JSON in dam.  The content of the JSON file needs to be translated using i18n.

The translation is happening for chinese, french and germany. The problem i am facing is after the translation all the JSON file have ??? for chinese,  few garbage character for french if the JSON file contains text like this, ë.

I think the issue is related to encoding. But i am not sure how to proceed further. Can anyone please help me in this.

I am doing the following

Get reference object of ResourceBundleProvider.

```
@Reference (target= "(component.name=org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.JcrBundleProvider)")    
ResourceBundleProvider  resourceBundleProvider;
```

After this getting the resourcebundle in the service method

```
ResourceBundle bundle = resourceBundleProvider.getResourceBundle(locale);    
I18n i18n = new I18n(resourceBundle);
```

Adding the value returned by i18n to JSONObject and constructing the JSON.

```
final String sample = dataObject.getString("sample");
sampleObject.put("data", i18n.get(sample));
```

I am passing the jsonpath to the Sightly.
The front end team will read it and construct the html using jquery.
In other words, the json is read in the jquery to construct the html page.

Comment: 1. what i18n service are you using to translate? 2. how are you viewing the translated JSON?

Comment: @AhmedMusallam I have edited the question please check now. In the html page all the translated text are displayed as `?????`

Comment: it could be that your OS cannot render those chars, assuming you are on windows, have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29458106/chinese-characters-showing-as-question-marks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue was related to encoding. 
I was not setting the encoding while creating the file.

It has been fixed now.